# Javascript - How to find adjacent tiles in a grid?

Tags: javascript

**Situation:**

I have a container with a simple 3x3 grid like this:
[image]

**Question:**

When I click a tile I want to get the adjacent tiles in an array.

**Example 1:**

If the center tile is selected I want these tiles in the array:
[image]

**Example 2:**

If the right tile in the middle row is selected I want these tiles in the array:
[image]

**Current Solution:**

Currently I do this:

1. get all tiles in an array called `battlefieldSlots`
2. get the selected tiles index in `currentSlotIndex`
3. push the tiles I need to an array called `slotTargets`

This works, but the approach seems a bit clumsy.
Especially since eventually I would like to have a solution that works with different grids (e.g. 4x4, 3x5, 7x7). I can't think of a good way to approach this.

Any help appreciated.

```
var slotTargets = [];

if (currentSlotIndex == 2) {
    slotTargets.push(null);
    slotTargets.push(null);
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 3));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 1));
} else if (currentSlotIndex == 3) {
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 3));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 1));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 3));
    slotTargets.push(null);
} else if (currentSlotIndex == 5) {
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 3));
    slotTargets.push(null);
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 3));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 1));
} else if (currentSlotIndex == 6) {
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 3));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 1));
    slotTargets.push(null);
    slotTargets.push(null);
} else {
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 3));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 1));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex + 3));
    slotTargets.push(battlefieldSlots.item(currentSlotIndex - 1));
}
```

Comment: Where is the HTML for your tiles?

Comment: Do you have any x/y coords for your tiles? Its simply a case of adding/subtracting 1 from the x & y position (and checking that is inside bounds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a `1D array` data structure to store your grid, it's a little complicated to check if an index is out-of-bound. `3` for example, we have no idea if it is `(0, 1)` or `(3, 0)`, so we need to have 4 variables to check edge conditions.

If you want the solution to be more elegant, using a `2D array` might help

```js
const col = 3; // width of your grid
const row = 3; // height of your grid

function getAround(index) {
    let around = [];

    // For Edge Condition
    index = Number( index );
    if( isNaN( index ) ) {
        throw new Error("Index should be a number.");
    }
    
    const leftEdge = index % col === 0; // Tile on very left edge
    const rightEdge = (index+1) % col === 0; // Tile on right edge
    const topEdge = Math.floor( index / col ) === 0; // Tile on top edge
    const bottomEdge = Math.floor( index / col ) === (row - 1); // Tile on bottom edge

    if( ! leftEdge ) around.push( index - 1 );
    if( ! rightEdge ) around.push( index + 1 );
    if( ! topEdge ) around.push( index - col );
    if( ! bottomEdge ) around.push( index + col );

    return around;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you

Comment: Quick Addition:
When it came to these parts:
`around.push( index + 1 )`

I stumbled with JS doing doing it's 1 + 5 = 15 acrobatics.
I solved this by adding `col = parseInt(col, 10);` to all numbers used in the calculation. Maybe you could add that somewhere?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That's because the `index` you passed to `getAround` is not a number. Check my updated  answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume you have an x & y position for your tiles (with 0,0 being top left in this example) it's somewhat easy to find the adjacent tiles

```js
function findAdjacentTiles(x,y,gridWidth,gridheight){
  return [[-1,0],[1,0],[0,-1],[0,1]] // all the possible directions
             .map( ([xd,yd]) => ([x+xd,y+yd]) ) // adjust the starting point
             .filter( ([x,y]) => x>=0 && x<gridWidth && y>=0 && y<gridheight) // filter out those out of bounds
}

console.log("for [1,1]:",  JSON.stringify(findAdjacentTiles(1,1,3,3)));
console.log("for [2,1]:",  JSON.stringify(findAdjacentTiles(2,1,3,3)));
```